# Rails 4.2.4 / Devise - How to allow nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I'm having some problems trying to clear some parameters for nested forms with Devise. Here is my code and in the end an explanation of what I tried already.

I've found a bunch of answers in SO but all of them seems to point to just put :address_attributes => [:etc], but it is not working for me.

#### User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, allow_destroy: true

end
```

#### Address

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Phone

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### The Form

```
  .row
    .col-md-3
      %p 2. Complete seus dados pessoais
    .col-md-9
      = simple_form_for @user, url: user_registration_path, method: :patch, class: 'form-inline' do |f|
        = f.input :name, label: 'Nome Completo'
        = f.input :birth_date, label: 'Data de Nascimento', start_year: 1910
        = f.input :cpf, label: 'CPF'
        .row
          = f.simple_fields_for @user_phone do |ff|
            .col-md-4
              = ff.input :country_code, label: 'Código do País'
            .col-md-4
              = ff.input :area_code, label: 'DDD'
            .col-md-4
              = ff.input :number, label: 'Telefone'

        = f.simple_fields_for @user_address do |ff|
          = ff.input :zip_code, label: 'CEP'
          = ff.input :street, label: 'Rua'
          = ff.input :street_number, label: 'Número'
          = ff.input :district, label: 'Bairro'
          = ff.input :complement, label: 'Complemento'
          = ff.input :state_id, collection: @states, label: 'Estado'
          = ff.input :city_id, collection: @cities, label: 'Cidade'
        = f.submit 'Salvar'
```

#### The Devise registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
    before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u| 
      # raise
      u.permit(:username, :name, :birth_date, :cpf, :phone_attributes =>    [:country_code, :area_code, :number], :address_attributes => [:zip_code, :street_number, :street, :district, :complement, :state_id, :city_id])
    end
  end
```

end

#### The log:

```
    tarted PATCH "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 18:31:22 -0200
    Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CiXxFEc9zv6WAf5Ow/Kv8ZDU84lAsdFXmLP0IeDlxGKgbjdOzS2+IlZ3NVFlwDKohQz0ix7m0uXOUGEg2na1HA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Teste", "birth_date(3i)"=>"29", "birth_date(2i)"=>"10", "birth_date(1i)"=>"2015", "cpf"=>"32323232", "phone"=>{"country_code"=>"55", "area_code"=>"3232", "number"=>"323232"}, "address"=>{"zip_code"=>"32212", "street"=>"dasdasdasdas", "street_number"=>"dasdasdasd", "district"=>"sdasdasdas", "complement"=>"asdasdasdsa", "state_id"=>"2", "city_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Salvar"}
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Unpermitted parameters: phone, address
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
       (0.1ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Completed 302 Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

If it try putting :address_attributes => [:etc], I get unpermitted params. If I try just :address => [:etc], I get "Attribute address not found for user".

I've tried puting in plural (:addresses_attributes) but it doesn't work.

The Devise controler is already configured in the routes, and allows me to edit all fields on the model itself, the problem is only in the nested models.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have is that your `fields_for` is not initializing your nested attributes correctly - the params should pass `phones_attributes` and `addresses_attributes` respectively.

Thus, you'd be best using the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controller: { registrations: "registrations" }

#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     build_resource({})
     self.resource.phones.build
     self.resource.addresses.build
     respond_with self.resource
   end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
#app/views/registrations/new.haml
...
= f.simple_fields_for :phones do |ff|
   ...
= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |ff|
   ...
```

This should set the correct attributes to be passed through your model.

Comment: Wow! I would never see that. Thank you so very much! It really solved it!